# Reprojecting GeoTIFF from WGS84 to UTM with gdalwarp?

Tags: coordinate-system, gdal, linux

I have a GeoTIFF image in WGS84 and when I try with gdalwarp to reproject to UTM, it has a problem.

Size of TIFF is  J: 15769, W: 60027

```
J_LeftTop：2.0705046510  W_LeftTop：0.4974727391；
J_RightTop：2.0702337994 W_RightTop：0.4996621899；
J_LeftBottom：2.0760866619    W_LeftBottom：0.4980068600；
J_RightBottom：2.0758219229 W_RightBottom：0.5002002912；
J_CNT：2.0731617464 W_CNT：0.4988380007
```

When I try:

```
gdalwarp -t_srs '+proj=utm +zone=12 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs' test.tif test_utm1.tif
```

> ERROR 1: Too many points (10201 out of 10201) failed to transform,
>   unable to compute output bounds.

What should I do differently?

Comment: Please provide more info on the source file, as reported by gdalinfo and gdalsrsinfo. Especially the extent and corner coordinates.

Comment: most likely problem is that your map is not in UTM12 (-114.0 0.0, -108.0 84.0)

Comment: Where on Earth should the data be placed?

Answer (score 0):

Trhough formula ：ZoneNumber = floor((LongTemp + 180)/6) + 1 I calculate zone for the point.Then I got the right ZoneNumber.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add the **s_srs** parameter? Input epsg is 4326 but perhaps the geotiff CRS definition is not the standard expected from GDAL.

Moreover are you sure about the **t_srs** parameter? Are your data on UTM12N zone?